# Using jQuery to get height of position:absolute content is running twice, the second time returning incorrect values

Tags: jquery, html, css

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paultrotter50/fdvC5/ shows the problem I am having with detecting the height of position absolute content.

I am creating a tabbed panel so users can choose a room type and then a room sub-type. The room subtypes (ul.sub-types) have a position of absolute so they can be positioned correctly.

When the user switches between room sub-types I need to use jQuery/javascript to detect the height of the ul.sub-types so that I can set the height of the whole panel (div.tab-panel - shown with a blue outline) to match its contents. This should mean the page content coming after the panel does not get overlapped by the absolutely positioned room subtypes.

Unfortunately the jQuery function seems to run twice - the first time it detects the correct value and adjusts the blue outlined tab-panel correctly. Then it immediately seems to run again and returns an incorrect value.

You can see this most clearly when you click on family in the left hand column and then the bottom Family Double on the right hand side. This has lots of items in the list so that the height change is emphasized.

Any advice on what is causing the problem and/or how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<section id="main_col">

<div class="tab-panel">

                                <ul id="room-types" class="left-tabs">

                                    <li class="type double selected">
                                        <input id="double" type="radio" name="room-type" checked="checked">
                                        <label for="double">Double

                                        <ul class="sub-types">

                                            <li class="selected">
                                                <input id="subtype1" type="radio" name="double-subtypes" value="subtype1" checked="checked">
                                            <label for="subtype1">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Classic Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype1 -->
                                         </li>


                                        <li>
                                            <input id="subtype2" type="radio" name="double-subtypes" value="subtype2">
                                            <label for="subtype2">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" width="124" height="70" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Classic Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype2 -->
                                         </li>

                                         <li>
                                            <input id="subtype3" type="radio" name="double-subtypes" value="subtype3">
                                            <label for="subtype3">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" width="124" height="70" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Classic Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype3 -->
                                         </li>
                                     </ul>
                                     </label>
                                </li><!-- end .type.double -->


                                <li class="type twin">
                                    <input id="twin" type="radio" name="room-type">
                                    <label for="twin">Twin

                                    <ul class="sub-types">

                                        <li class="selected">
                                            <input id="subtype1" type="radio" name="twin-subtypes" value="subtype1" checked="checked">
                                            <label for="subtype1">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" width="124" height="70" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Twin Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype1 -->
                                         </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <input id="subtype2" type="radio" name="twin-subtypes" value="subtype2">
                                            <label for="subtype2">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" width="124" height="70" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Twin Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype2 -->
                                         </li>

                                         <li>
                                            <input id="subtype3" type="radio" name="twin-subtypes" value="subtype2">
                                            <label for="subtype3">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" width="124" height="70" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Twin Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype3 -->
                                         </li>
                                     </ul>
                                     </label>
                                </li><!-- end .type.twin -->


                                <li class="type family">
                                    <input id="family" type="radio" name="room-type">
                                    <label for="family">Family

                                    <ul class="sub-types">

                                        <li class="selected">
                                            <input id="subtype1" type="radio" name="family-subtypes" value="subtype1" checked="checked">
                                            <label for="subtype1">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" width="124" height="70" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Family Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype1 -->
                                         </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <input id="subtype2" type="radio" name="family-subtypes" value="subtype2">
                                            <label for="subtype2">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" width="124" height="70" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Family Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype2 -->
                                         </li>

                                         <li>
                                            <input id="subtype3" type="radio" name="family-subtypes" value="subtype3">
                                            <label for="subtype3">

                                                <span class="col2">
                                                   <img src="img/pg-specific/left_col/room_sea_view.jpg" width="124" height="70" alt=" "> 
                                                </span><!-- end col2 -->

                                                <span class="col1">
                                                    <span class="title">Family Double</span>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 1</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 2</li>
                                                        <li>bullet item 3</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </span><!-- end col1 -->
                                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                            </label><!-- end lable for subtype3 -->
                                         </li>
                                     </ul>
                                     </label>
                                </li><!-- end .type.family -->


                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

​
CSS:

```
/*--- booking tab panels --- */

                    .tab-panel ul.sub-types {display:none;}
                    .tab-panel { position:relative; width:100%; border: 1px solid blue; height:500px; font-size:0.9em;}
                    .tab-panel input[type="radio"]:checked + label ul.sub-types {display:block; position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px; width:80%;}
                    .tab-panel ul.sub-types > li .col2, .tab-panel ul.sub-types > li .col1 ul  {display:none;}
                    .tab-panel ul.sub-types input[type="radio"]:checked  + label .col2, .tab-panel ul.sub-types input[type="radio"]:checked + label .col1 ul  {display:block;}
                    #main_col .tab-panel input, #main_col .tab-panel label {float:left;}
                    #main_col .tab-panel input {clear:both; margin-right:10px; width:auto;}
                    #room-types > li > input[type="radio"]:checked + label { font-weight:bold; background-color: #bfb2b5; width:60%; }
                    #room-types > li > input[type="radio"]:checked + label .sub-types { font-weight:normal;}
                    #room-types > li > label {padding:7px 0px 5px 5px;}
                    .tab-panel .sub-types {background-color: #e0d7c1; }

                    .tab-panel .col1, .tab-panel .col2 {display:block;}
                    .tab-panel .col1 {float:left; width:58%; margin-left:10%; margin-top:10px; margin-right:0px;}
                    .tab-panel .col2 {float:right; width:25%; padding:10px; margin-right:0px;}
                    .tab-panel .sub-types li.selected label {width:100%;}
                    .tab-panel .sub-types li.selected  label { background-color:#f3ebde;}
                    .tab-panel .sub-types input[type="radio"]:checked + label {background-color:#f3ebde; background-image: url(../img/core/radio-on-cream-bg.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:7px 13px; cursor:auto;}
                    .tab-panel .sub-types li label  {background: url(../img/core/radio-off-sand-bg.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:7px 13px; cursor:pointer; }
                    #main_col .tab-panel .sub-types li label {margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:5px;}
                    .tab-panel .sub-types li label li {background-image:url("../img/core/tick-description-text.gif"); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 0px 2px; padding-left:15px; width: 100px; float: left; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:3px;}
                    .tab-panel .sub-types li label ul {width:100%; float:left; margin-top:8px;} 
                    .tab-panel .sub-types li label img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
                    .tab-panel .sub-types input[type="radio"]:checked + label .title { font-weight:bold;}​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* book page panels -------------------------------------- */


$('.sub-types li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input:radio').attr('checked', false)
    $(this).children('input:radio').attr('checked', true)
    $('.sub-types li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var panelHeight = $(this).closest('ul.sub-types').height();
    alert("height: " + panelHeight);
    $(this).closest(".tab-panel").css('height', panelHeight)

});

}); /* end $(document).ready(function() */​
```

Comment: I don't know, this looks like it's working to me. Also, why are you trying to set the height of a panel, just use height: auto, no?

Comment: Works for me in FF and Chrome. Nothing in IE8. I was getting an alert, but that is gone now.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for you input. Unfortunately I wish it was that simple. If you set the panel height to auto, any content beneath it slips behind the .sub-types because they have an absolute position and therefore their height doesn't force their parent container to become taller. This becomes more evident in this fiddle whre I have added some content beneath http://jsfiddle.net/paultrotter50/fdvC5/9/

Comment: Hi buildakicker. That's weird that it is working fine for you. So you don't get two alerts each time you click a sub-type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the reason it's getting run twice is that your hidden elements underneath are also being clicked. Try specifying a :visible selector. I also had to switch the click event to On, and bind it to a different dom element otherwise the click event would bind only to whichever element was marked as 'li:visible' at document.ready:

```
$('.sub-types').on('click', 'li:visible', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input:radio').attr('checked', false)
    $(this).children('input:radio').attr('checked', true)
    $('.sub-types li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var panelHeight = $(this).closest('ul.sub-types').height();
    alert("height: " + panelHeight);
    $(this).closest(".tab-panel").css('height', panelHeight)

});
```

Comment: Hi Jeff - thanks for your help. This solved the issue perfectly. Thanks also for your explanation of how and why to use '.on' which I'm sure will help me in the future. For anyone else who is interested [here is the working fiddle of Jeff's solution](http://jsfiddle.net/paultrotter50/fdvC5/11/)